# Conversion into percentage

Tags: percentages

I have a very basic algo wherein each person gives an opinion about an article which has a score. All opinions add up points to the article score. For example, If person says I like it, article gets 5 points and likewise, -5 for dislike. In addition to this, there are some additional points based on person's rating. For example, if a person has good rating himself, we assign 25 additional points to that article. so if that person likes the article, we give 30 points instead of 5.

in the end I want to calculate score between the range of 1%-100%..but as you can see, we can't use simple percentage formula here...let's say if we have 5 people with good ratings and they all like that article, score will become 150 and if we divide that with 5 answer will be 50 which doesn't make much sense. Is there any way or formula for such variable scores? If it was as simple as 5 points for each like then I could have used (5/25)*100 = total %age but it won't work in my case.

Honestly speaking, I don't know where to start this so I haven't done anything as of yet. Sorry for my dumbness.

Answer (score 0):

The percentage is a function of the ratio between actual score and possible score based on involved voters so far.

The full range is then calculated as:

- Upper limit assumes all voters have voted positively, and includes all associated bonuses
- Lower limit assumes all voters have voted negatively, and includes all associated deductions

The actual value you already know, so now you need to decide if you scale the range from 0% to 100%, or -100%  to 100%, and thus how much to scale the actual value by to get your final percentage.